# What is the name of that widespread blues lick and how to play it?

Tags: guitar, blues, rock-n-roll

I would like to improve my guitar solos and to add a lick to them. The one I'm thinking off is used in many blues songs, but also rock'n'roll, punk rock, etc. One example that I can find is the whole outro to [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkEQCh0RDJY).

The riff is also used, for instance, at the end of Feelings by The Offspring.

What is the name of this riff? I tried to look it up but the only things I find are compilations or 10 guitar riffs to learn, none of which contain it. I tried to pick it by ear but I can't manage to be as fluid as I would like, so I guess there is a technique I'm missing.

Comment: I don't think the lick has a name per se. The rythm part seems to be a shuffle in E. In the lick, he seems to be playing the E pentatonic minor in box 3. He's just doing it really quickly. And he uses a repeating phrase using sixteenth notes... there are loads of variations of similar phrases. I can be more specific once I can play this on my guitar

Comment: Never heard of guitar licks having names before. If you want to learn it, slow it down using software.

Comment: There must be thousands of short licks such as this. Imagine each having a name..? Vtc as not in accordance with site rules.

Comment: with  VIDEO-speed 25%  you can copy this lick (model-learning)

Comment: Thank you all. I will try to practice it with 25% speed, and also to practice my sweep picking, it seems like this is the technique used.